# How can I efficiently manage my stash unit's space/weight?

Tags: fallout-76

Fallout 76 has a Stash Unit that each player gets.  It has a weight limit of 400.  This means that overtime it will fill up and you will not be able to stash any more items into it.  400 may seem like a decent amount, but having played only for a few hours in the beta and a few hours after launch, my stash unit is full.

I am finding it increasingly harder to manage my stash.  I have a small base setup at my camp, but the only stash unit I have is the *actual* stash unit box.  There are other containers one can build, but at level 17, I still do not have a single crafting plan for any of the other stash units, and thus I cannot build them. I also do not know if these other containers are independent of one another, or are all apart of the combined stash.

It seems this 400 weight restriction is quite a nuisance to many players, and supposedly Bethesda will be addressing the issue [sometime soon](https://metro.co.uk/2018/11/14/what-is-the-fallout-76-stash-limit-and-will-it-be-increased-8138411/).  In the meantime, what are effective measures one can take to handle their stash?

Comment: I heard that they increased the weight of some items (such as bobby pins) to balance them out. It might be worth looking at the item's weight and deciding what is 'worth it's weight in gold' until you're 17 or they put some fixes in place.

Comment: I actually like the fact that there are 'regular' storage boxes you have to unlock. To fix the storage problem you could simply start with a stash and a simple mailbox for example. The stuff stored in the stash would be safe the stuff in the mailbox would not be. It then turns into a more defensive base building aspect which i personally really like.

Comment: One of the tooltips on the loading screen indicates that the other containers in your base also share the same 400 weight limit, though I haven't tested it myself yet. If you haven't been already... make sure you're breaking all your junk down into raw materials before depositing them into your stash. The weight of the raw components is way less than the weight of the original junk.

Comment: @king14nyr yup I do that.  It be realllllllly hard to use the stash without doing that at a minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few ways I manage my storage,

1. **Always scrap junk before depositing.** That way you don't have heavier junk items in your stash and everything is condensed down to the components making things easier to find.
2. **Useless Items.** If you're near a water source, you probably don't want to store dirty/boiled water in your stash since it's easily accessible. Additionally, I've personally found myself forgetting about those higher level legendaries by the time I get to that level, so I've stopped storing them and starting selling them. Likewise, I know I'm never going to be interested in laser/energy weaponry so I've started giving away all of that respective ammo.
3. **Bulk Components.** Some scrap components are lighter weight when bulk than their scrap counterparts (not all, definitely not all). More details [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341238/select-where-to-build-from) thanks to Timmy Jim for providing the link. Bulk components can be used just as regular individual components and will be broken apart on an as needed basis.
4. **Odd situations.** I have tier 3 pack rat (-75% junk weight). This makes some previously already lightweight items (like screws) weigh nothing. Obviously there's a risk of dropping your junk on death (PVP or PVE) so you have to determine if that's a risk you're willing to take since pack rat doesn't apply to your stash.
5. **Avoiding Stash.** I have about 250 carry weight now between my deep pocketed trapper armor that gives +10 carry weight and the strength perk card that gives +10/20/30/40 carry weight. Helps me avoid having to put things I would have otherwise put in my stash.

Comment: It doesn't help that at the moment my [Camp keeps disappearing](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/9xajky/my_camp_is_gone_fallout_76/) from the map when I join a server.  These are some good tips.  I currently have 11 strength (12 depending on the time of day due to a perk) which allows me to carry quite a significant amount.  I also have some pocketed gear as well.  I think the biggest problem is mainly point 5 that you make, as well as managing junk.  The game doesn't make it easy to know what junk you may need to repair armor and weapons, so managing what junk to keep can be tough.

Comment: One question though, I do know about the bulk scrapping method you mentioned in point 2, but If you tap into a bulk supply (say you need 10 steel but only have 9 loose steel pieces and the rest in a bulk steel package), does it then break open the bulk supply? So for this example, after the 9 loose steel is used and the 1 piece is taken from a bulk supply, is the bulk supply broken apart into its individual pieces?

Comment: Doing periodic cleanups of your broken down junk really does help, too. There's only so much steel and wood scraps you really need, especially since they are so abundant and you'll always get more... whenever I get to my stash limit, I typically bundle those two up until I have only a couple hundred or so scraps of each and sell the bundles for some easy caps.

Comment: It seems bulking isn't really a good idea for saving space in a stash.  The bulk items actually (most of the time) weigh more, as pointed out [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341238/select-where-to-build-from).  That question also links to a nice Reddit post with a spreadsheet that shows how you are actually consuming space by bulking item.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize Packrat has an effect on the outcome of whether or not it is beneficial to bulk, and obviously Packrat doesn't benefit your stash.